# python IndexError: string index out of range when i try to get single characters from a string

Tags: python

I'am trying to make a simple socket server in python that is able to serve multiple files but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webserver.py", line 43, in <module>
    if b[x] == "G":
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I don't get what the problem is as the character I'm trying to get is perfectly in range and has left me completely confused. The specific part that has the error in it is supposed to get the desired file from the request.
My code:

```
import sys;
import socket;

port = 80
host = socket.gethostbyname("localhost")
file = ""
file_ready = 0
x = 0
y = 0

#Create socket
print("# Creating socket")
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#Bind port & host
print("# Binding to port " + str(port))
try:
    s.bind((host, port))
except socket.gaierror:
    print("# An error occured whilst binding the port\nerrorno. " + socket.errno)

#Main loop
while 1:
    #Listen for request
    print("# Now listening for incoming requests")
    s.listen(5)

    #Accept request
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print(("# Connected with " + addr[0]))

    #Receive data from client as "b"
    b = conn.recv(1024)
    print("# Received data")

    #Decode "b", encoding = "utf-8"
    b = b.decode("utf-8")
    print("# Data decoded")

    #Request processing
    print("# Processing request")
    while 1:
        if b[x] == "G":
            x = x + 1
            if b[x] == "E":
                x = x + 1
                if b[x] == "T":
                    x = x + 1
                    if b[x] == " ":
                        x = x + 1
                        if b[x] == "/":
                            x = x + 1
                            while 1:
                                if b[x] == "/":
                                    file_ready = file_ready + 1
                                    break
                                else:
                                    file[y] = b[x]
                                    x = x + 1
                                    y = y + 1      
                            if file_ready == 1:
                                print("# Request processed")
                                break
                            else:
                                pass  
                        else:
                            x = x + 1
                    else:
                        x = x + 1
                else:
                    x = x + 1
            else:
                x = x + 1
        else:
            x = x + 1 

    #Prepare file to send to client
    print("# Preparing file")
    f = open(file, "r+")
    content = f.read()
    f.close()
    content_len = len(content)

    #Send data to the client
    conn.send('''
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Server: Test
    Last-Modified: Tue, 18 Feb 2020 15:12:00 GMT
    Content-Length: ''' + content_len + '''
    Connection: close
    b\'''' + content + "'")
    print("# Data sent")
```

Comment: x is greater than the last index of the string if you get this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't resetting `x` to zero between connections.

The first connection may work perfectly fine, but for subsequent connections, `x` is not in range.

That said, you may want to just use `b.split()` to parse that string – or better yet, since you're apparently implementing a rudimentary HTTP/1.0 server, use [the built-in batteries for HTTP servers](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/http.server.html#module-http.server)!

For the sake of exercise, though, here's an adaptation of your code that works for multiple subsequent connections:

```
import socket


def handle_request(conn):
    request = conn.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
    bits = request.split()  # Split by any runs of whitespace (non-spec-compliant but works for now)
    verb = bits[0]
    if verb == "GET":
        filename = bits[1].lstrip("/")
    else:
        conn.sendall(b"HTTP/1.1 400 Error\r\n\r\nInvalid verb")
        return

    with open(filename, "rb") as f:  # Warning: this allows reading any file on your syste
        content = f.read()

    conn.sendall(b"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n")
    conn.sendall(f"Content-length: {len(content)}\r\n".encode())
    conn.sendall(b"\r\n")
    conn.sendall(content)
    conn.close()


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    s.bind(("localhost", 8081))
    s.listen(5)
    while 1:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print(("# Connected with " + addr[0]))
        try:
            handle_request(conn)
        finally:
            conn.close()
finally:
    s.close()
```